# Size variation in a Imagemagick montage

Tags: random, imagemagick

I try to have random space between my images in an Imagemagick montage.
My original script is:

```
montage images/* -mode Concatenate -tile 12x -geometry +10+10 -background white tile.png
```

…and I need something like:

```
montage images/* -mode Concatenate -tile 12x -geometry +($RANDOM%200+0)+($RANDOM%200+0) -background white tile.png
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The `-geometry` is only evaluated once at the start, so I don't think your intended approach is going to work. You can either grab the 12 images and total up their widths plus 11 randomly sized gaps and then create a canvas big enough to lay your images out on, or make a bunch of spacer blocks to move your images right and down by random amounts.

So, this is a rough starting point of how you might build something up maybe... I know you don't want the background yellow, but I am setting it that way so you can see what I am doing. I am basically laying out a red, a green and a blue image in a horizontal strip, but adding randomly sized spacer blocks in and I have coloured these in varying shades of grey so you can see them.

```
convert -background yellow                   \
   red.png xc:gray20[100x100]                \
   \( xc:gray40[80x80] green.png -append \)  \
   xc:gray60[25x25]                          \
   \( xc:gray80[200x200] blue.png -append \) \
   +append  tile.png
```

[image]

Each time an image and a spacer appear together in parentheses, that is basically a spacer ABOVE the image with the image itself `-appended` BELOW. Each time a spacer occurs on its own, that is basically to the right of the preceding image, and at the end, the `+append` joins all the blocks up side-by-side.

To understand what I am doing, you need to appreciate that `-append` places images top-to-bottom, one above the other and that `+append` places images side-by-side next to each other.

I am suggesting you create a script to build the command up.

Basically, you could make a strip like this, then another one of 12 and use `-append` to stick them together. Obvioulsy you want to make the background, and all the spacers, white.